# How to check Python SQL Query for results and update accordingly

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, tkinter

On button click, a SQL query is run and the SQL rows update my Tkinter Entry rows.
All rows do not delete or reset unless the new SQL query produces enough rows to fill up my Tkinter Entry rows.

If the SQL query only produces 1 name, only the self.output0 will reset with the new SQL data.

If the SQL query only produces 2 names, only the self.output0 AND self.output1 will reset with new SQL data.

If the SQL query produces 10 names, self.output0 THROUGH self.output10 will reset with new SQL data.

I would like to have all Tkinter Entrys reset on each button click.  If there is no SQL output for a particular row, then Tkinter Entry row should show blank.

Any ideas on how I can check SQL for this and make it update correctly?

**Update**  Results should hold a tuple of the number of rows.  So I guess I need to check if results is less than 10. If it is, then I need to take the remainder and use Tkinter to delete the rows associated with the remaining numbers.

Tkinter is currently updating all rows no matter what.  If SQL does not provide a new row, for some reason, Tkinter is pulling data from the old query over.

```
    import os
    import pypyodbc
    import tkinter
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import messagebox
    from tkinter import BOTH, END, LEFT


    class Adder(ttk.Frame):
    """The adders gui and functions."""
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        self.init_gui()

    def calculate(self):
        firstname = str(self.first_entry.get())
        lastname = str(self.last_entry.get())     
        license = str(self.lic_entry.get())
        if (firstname and not lastname and not license):  # "You entered first name."

           try:
                connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=MYSERVER;Database=MYDATABASE;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
            except pypyodbc.Error as ex:
                sqlstate = ex.args[0]
                if sqlstate == '28000':
                    self.answer_label['text'] = "You do not have access." 
            cursor = connection.cursor() 
            SQLCommand = ("SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, L_LICNUMBER "      
                "FROM dbo.My_table "   # table name
                "with (nolock)"
                "WHERE FIRSTNAME = ?")
            Values = [firstname]
            cursor.execute(SQLCommand,Values)
            results = cursor.fetchmany(20)
            if results:


                self.output0.delete(0, END)
                self.output0.insert(0,results[0])
                self.output1.delete(0, END)
                self.output1.insert(0,results[1])
                self.output2.delete(0, END)
                self.output2.insert(0,results[2])
                self.output3.delete(0, END)
                self.output3.insert(0,results[3])
                self.output4.delete(0, END)
                self.output4.insert(0,results[4])
                self.output5.delete(0, END)
                self.output5.insert(0,results[5])
                self.output6.delete(0, END)
                self.output6.insert(0,results[6])
                self.output7.delete(0, END)
                self.output7.insert(0,results[7])
                self.output8.delete(0, END)
                self.output8.insert(0,results[8])
                self.output9.delete(0, END)
                self.output9.insert(0,results[9])
                connection.close()

    def init_gui(self):
        """Builds GUI."""

        self.root.option_add('*tearOff', 'FALSE')

        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew') # this starts the entire form


        # Input Boxes and Button

        self.first_entry = tkinter.Entry(self, width=28) # first input box
        self.first_entry.grid(sticky='', column=1, row=1) 

        self.last_entry = tkinter.Entry(self, width=28) # second input box
        self.last_entry.grid(sticky='', column=2, row=1) 

        self.lic_entry = tkinter.Entry(self, width=28) # third input box
        self.lic_entry.grid(sticky='', column=3, row=1) 


        self.calc_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Search', command=self.calculate) # button
        self.calc_button.grid(column=4, row=1, columnspan=1, sticky='w', padx=14)

        # Output frame for answers

        self.output0 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, bd=0,)
        self.output0.grid(column=0, row=6, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output1 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, bd=0,)
        self.output1.grid(column=0, row=7, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output2 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, bd=0,)
        self.output2.grid(column=0, row=8, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output3 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, bd=0,)
        self.output3.grid(column=0, row=9, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output4 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, bd=0,)
        self.output4.grid(column=0, row=10, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output5 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, bd=0,)
        self.output5.grid(column=0, row=11, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output6 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, bd=0,)
        self.output6.grid(column=0, row=12, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output7 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, bd=0,)
        self.output7.grid(column=0, row=13, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output8 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, bd=0,)
        self.output8.grid(column=0, row=14, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.output9 = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, bd=0,)
        self.output9.grid(column=0, row=15, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)       


    if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    Adder(root)
    root.resizable(width=False, height=False) # locks window from being resized
    root.mainloop()
```

The button is only resetting the specific number of rows being changed by the current SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Use an array to hold your entry variables, and then just iterate over the array to reset everything

```
def init_gui(self):
    ...
    self.entries = []
    for row in range(10):
        entry = tkinter.Entry(self, width=150, bd=0,)
        entry.grid(column=0, row=row+6, columnspan=5, padx=100, pady=0)
        self.entries.append(entry)
    ...
...
def calculate(self):
    ...
    # delete all of the old data
    for entry in self.entries:
        entry.delete(0, "end")

    # insert the new data
    # Note: if there are fewer results than entries, zip will
    # return only as many items as there are results
    for (entry, value) in zip(self.entries, result):
        entry.insert(0, value)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Bryan.  I am going through your example and trying to get it working.  It's currently not working but am I on the right track with this?  https://paste.ofcode.org/Q5brVGwqb7NzTHjR7iz3dP  I actually got my program working by running a new SQL query for each and every row but that doesn't seem efficient.